# Does free iWork on iOS entitle me to free iWork to Mac?

Tags: ios, iwork

I have recently become the proud owner of a new iPhone 5s and have benefitted from the free iWork apps that are available to new devices.

I also own a 2012 MacBook Pro running Mavericks. Now I have the iWork apps on my iPhone, does it entitle me to them on my Mac via 'purchased' or are they different apps altogether being on different platforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually no, iOS and OSX version of iWorks are 2 different softwares although linked by iCloud (AppStore & Mac AppStore "are" independent). iWork for OSX is free for every Mac bought after October 1st 2013.

There are [some workaround to get the 3 OSX apps (Pages, Keynote & Numbers) for free](http://www.maketecheasier.com/get-iwork-for-free-in-mavericks/) without any illegal download.

Does Apple know that or do they do that on purpose ? That a good question that I do not know the answer.

Comment: Nice link! You should probably summarize their tutorial here, just in case that page gets taken down sometime in the future.